# Weapon damage range calculator no error but it's not working

Tags: javascript

Because I'm too lazy to calculate every time I decided to make a calculator with jquery.

For some reason it's not working and I don't know why so I'm here to ask you guys for help.

Here's a [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/HorseNamedDeath/f5k1Lbrj/)

> Damage Formula: 
>   AbaseEq: Damage Range of weapon (e.g: 800~1000) 
>   up difference: weapon up- armor up (e.g: 5-3:2 -> up difference:2 -> 15% if difference was 1 it would be 10%) 
>   Aeq: AbaseEq(1+up difference in %)

Codes:

```
        <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Base Attack (Without any equipment equipped): </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input placeholder="e.g: 290" id="abase">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Weapon Attack Range: </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input placeholder="e.g: 800-1000" id="abaseeq">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Weapon + ?</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input placeholder="e.g: 9" id="weapon+">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Enemy Defence + ? </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input placeholder="e.g: 6" id="enemydef+">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="calculate">
  Calculate
  </button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calculate').on('click', function() {
    var abase = $('#abase').val();
    var abaseEq = $('#abaseeq').val();
    var abaseEqLength = abaseEq.length;
    abaseEqLength -= 1;
    var weaponlvl = $('#weaponup').val();
    var enemydeflvl = $('#enemydefup').val();
    var weaponup=parseInt(weaponlvl);
    var enemydefup=parseInt(enemydeflvl);
    var updifference = weaponup - enemydefup;
    var plusdifference = [0, '10%', '15%', '22%', '32%', '43%', '54%', '65%', '90%', '120%', '200%'];
    var negdifference = {};
    var result;
    var aeqmin=0;
    var aeqmax=0;
    var lowestdamage="";
    var maxdamage="";
    var negindex;
    var negindexplus = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= abaseEqLength; i++) {
      if (abaseEq[i] == '-') {
        negindex = i;
        negindexplus += (negindex + 1);
      }
    }
    for (var x = 0; x < negindex; x++) {
      lowestdamage = lowestdamage + abaseEq[x];
      console.log("Lowest Damage: " + lowestdamage);
    }
    for (var y = negindexplus; y <= abaseEqLength; y++) {
      maxdamage = maxdamage + abaseEq[y];
      console.log("Max Damage: " + maxdamage);
    }
    if (updifference => 0 && updifference <= 10) {
      updifference = plusdifference[updifference];
      console.log("updifference: "+updifference);
      result = "pos";
    }
    if (updifference < 0 && updifference >= -10) {
      var negarray = negdifference * -1;
      negdifference[updifference] = plusdifference[negarray];
    }
    var mindamage = parseInt(lowestdamage);
    var maxidamage = parseInt(maxdamage);
    if (result == "pos") {
      aeqmin = mindamage * (1 + plusdifference[updifference]);
      aeqmax = maxidamage * (1 + plusdifference[updifference]);
    }
    if (aeqmax > 0) {
      $('#result').html = aeqmin + "~" + aeqmax;
    }
  }); // calculate on click function
}); // document ready
```

Comment: `$('#abaseeq').val` does not return you the value. it should be `$('#abaseeq').val()`

Comment: Did you try debugging your code by printing all the values to your console?

Comment: You also need to convert the string returned by `val()` to numbers or else you will get undefined behavior. Also you will probably have to take special care in converting `abaseEq` from a string like `"800-1000"` to whatever type it is you're actually expecting. As it is, that part of the code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I did changes in jsfiddle according to you @BlackPearl

Comment: Also, avoid using special characters like `+` in your element id, as it would mean that you have to escape it in selectors. Like `$('#weapon\\+')` instead of `$('#weapon+')` .

Comment: I changed $('#weapon+') to $('#weaponup') But I can't convert them to integer yet. Because I have to use them like a array so I can use them in variables like lowestdamage and maxdamage later I use parseInt to convert them to integer.

Comment: I would suggest you to print values to the console after every step to check if it all goes as intended. That way, you can know what actually goes wrong and fix it.